# Copy the root partition to another location at boot time

Tags: linux, debian

I have a Debian 9 install on my USB flash drive which I customized to my needs. what I need now is a way to copy all of the contents of the flash drive to a location on the internal HDD of the host computer and boot from the new location so basically like [this](http://reboot.pro/topic/14547-linux-load-your-root-partition-to-ram-and-boot-it/) but instead of copying to the ram I need to copy it to the internal HDD. and before someone asks why I'm doing it this way the answer is because I need to debug multiple machines at my workplace without dealing with the slowness of the USB drive. the installation size is somewhat large(about 5gb) therefore I can' load it into the ram (the host PC only has 2gb of ram).

Comment: Why do you have a 5GB debug image?

Comment: it has a custom software installed on it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You'll just have to create a filesystem beforehand and use that instead of `tmpfs` in the tutorial you linked. Your options are a spare partition or logical volume, or a loop-mounted file on some existing filesystem (if you can afford keeping that mounted during debugging). You have to include the appropriate `mkfs` tool into your initramfs (look for `copy_exec` in `man initramfs-tools`) or require an already existing filesystem.